# Getting initial state from redux when navigating directly to url

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

When user navigation to app ex: http://myapp.mydomain.com
I initialize a bunch of stuff, make requests to auth the user based on a cookie etc. This setup the main state of my main-reducer.

If a user navigation directly by pasting let say: http://myapp.mydomain.com/userProfile

The main state, will never be setupped. So the trick I'm using is putting the last part of the url (userProfile) in a cookie (or somewhere else) and redirecting to http://myapp.mydomain.com. After auth and requests, I the redirect back to the page the user wants to view. This works, but feels wrong. I was wondering: is there a better way of doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically you'd have something like `RootContainer` that is the upper most component, where you can have all these logics to be triggered no matter the route. And the trigger should be `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` so that it gets invoked only once when the user loads the page.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've been working like crazy! I did what you suggested and it worked pretty good! Did not think about the root container. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make the route `/userProfile` as protected route.

Only if the user is authenticated he can see that page if not redirect to root page and re-validate the user.

Comment: Yeah, I do that basically (without the protected route). But it will be definitely safer with your suggestion. Thanks!